# Why does it take longer for CBCharacteristics to receive a write value than it does to update a value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I have CoreBluetooth enabled in one of my apps. There is a central iOS device, and up to 2 peripheral iOS devices that can connect to the central.

I have implemented upstream communication by using one characteristic on the peripherals that the central subscribes to, and I have implemented downstream communication by using another characteristic on the peripherals that the central stores and writes to using `writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:`

These are setup in the peripheral like this:

```
upstream = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:pipeUUID properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify value:nil permissions:0];
downstream = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:downstreamUUID properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];
```

---

When sending data downstream, it typically looks like this:

```
NSData* data = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d", AppStateID, SomeValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[_peripheral1 writeValue:data forCharacteristic:_peripheral1Downstream type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

This implementation does work and it works quite well, but I've noticed something that gets in the way at times.

When I'm sending data from the peripheral to the central via the upstream characteristic, the central receives the data almost instantaneously, typically on the same frame. However, when I'm sending data from the central to the peripheral via the downstream characteristic, it can take anywhere from 0.5 seconds to 5 seconds for the peripheral to receive the data.

This isn't a huge issue, but it would certainly be better for the user experience if it didn't take so long for them to communicate.

---

### So my questions are:

1. Is there anything wrong with my implementation in the first place?
2. If yes, what is the proper way to do this?
3. If no, is there any way to optimize the communication from the central to the peripheral OR is there a similar *notifying* characteristic that I can use to send data downstream instead of upstream?

---

If it's related, I will note that I do get a recurring error from the write requests even though they do succeed.

> Write error: Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=241 "Unknown ATT error." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown ATT error.}

Comment: `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse` takes longer than `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse`. I guess that "notify" doesn't waits for a response (doing a `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse` like). Still, up to 5 seconds seems long. Maybe you have something blocking on the thread somewhere.

Comment: I guess I don't really need WriteWithResponse. If I do a WriteWithoutResponse characteristic, it is basically instantaneous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implementation seems fine but in the Peripheral side code, you need to respond to the write request with a success else the central will time out and give an error after 5 sec or so - the one you are getting above. The value would still get updated on Peripheral but central has no way of knowing that unless you respond like (Swift):

```
self.peripheralManager.respondToRequest(request, withResult: CBATTError.Success)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! For others that may find this, the 2023 syntax is: peripheralManager?.respond(to: request, withResult: .success)